# Cucumber run @SpringBootApplication.main method

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber

I have cucumber working with `spring-boot` and the context and components are available but `@SpringBootApplication.main` is not being run so various connections aren't available. Is there a way to make Cucumber invoke the `spring-boot` `main` method? This works for the context and components but does not invoke `TheApplication.main`:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class TheApplication {
... connect to stuff
```

and the steps file:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootApplication
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TheApplication.class, loader = SpringBootContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestCreateSteps {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of judicious refactoring solved the issue. Moving connection stuff to the class that needs the connection and using `TimeUnit` in the test to wait for it to initialise. Test is now working:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration()
public class TestCreateSteps {
  // Previously controlled by TheApplication
  // AccountService now controls itself via application.properties
  @Autowired
  private AccountService accountService;
  ...
}
```